# How to properly display all the english definition in just one loop without separation in php?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

The logical error display is that the english word that has more meaning are displayed like this:

```
English word: lie (1)
Definition: not honest

English word: lie (1)
Definition: deliberately say something untrue

English word: lie (2)
Definition: to stretch out on a surface that is slanted or horizontal

English word: lie (2)
Definition: to be positioned on and supported by a horizontal surface
```

I want the output to be displayed like this:

```
English word: lie (1)
Definition: 1. not honest
            2. deliberately say something untrue
```

If it has the same word with different meaning this should be the output:

```
English word: lie (1)
Definition: 1. not honest
            2. deliberately say something untrue

English word: lie (2)
Definition: 1. to stretch out on a surface that is slanted or horizontal
            2. to be positioned on and supported by a horizontal surface
```

Here's my code:

```
    <?php                                   

    $search = $_POST['word'];

    $query = "SELECT *" .
             " FROM english, english_meaning, maranao, filipino, translate". 
             " WHERE english.eng_id = english_meaning.eng_id and english.eng_id = translate.eng_id and maranao.mar_id = translate.mar_id and filipino.fil_id = translate.fil_id and english.english_word like '$search%'";

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

            if($num_rows==0)
            {
                echo "No Results Found. Please try again";
            }


                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                ?>
                    <div style = " background-color: #daeaff; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px;">
                    <font size='3' face='Times New Roman'>

                        English word: <b><?php echo $row['english_word']; ?></b><br>
                        Definition:<b><div style="width:600px; border:0px solid orange; margin-left: 79px; word-wrap:break-word; margin-top: -18px;"><?php echo $row['definition'] ?></b></div>

                    </font>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo "<br>"; ?>

                <?php
                }
            }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Add from your sql statement LIMIT 1

Comment: It will only display one definition.

Comment: How do you come up with the numbers in the brackets, example: `lie (1)`?

Comment: I just added it by myself

Comment: it would help to see some more of the column names (maybe even table structure). how do you keep track that some definitions of a word go together but others are separate? (how do you know lie(1) has 2 definitions and lie(2) has 2 different definitions?)

Answer (score 1):

> A couple of notes on the code:
>
> - It is subject to SQL injection. You should stop using the `mysql_*` functions, they have been deprecated, and replace them with `msqli_*`/PDO methods, and parameterized queries.
> - The HTML needs improvement too: you should not have cross-tags (e.g.: `<b><div>...</b></div>`), and avoid obsolete tags that are no longer supported in HTML5 (e.g.: `<font>`).

You could achieve what you want by keeping track of the previous word, and then displaying the whole information or just a part of it. Something like this (in pseudo-code):

1. Initialize `previous_word` variable to "".
2. While there are still rows (fetch):

   1. If the English word is not the same as the `previous_word`.

      1. Print "English word: " + word.
   2. Print definition.
   3. Update `previous_word` with the value of the current word.

---

Modifying the code from your question, the result would look like this (only the loop part):

```
// AM - variable that will hold the previous word
$previous_word = "";
$row = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    // AM - Show the word only if it's a new one    
    if ($row["english_word"] != $previous_word) { 

        // AM - close the previous word definition
        if ($row > 0) { echo "</div><br>"; }

    ?>
    <div style = " background-color: #daeaff; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px; font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:3;">
            English word: <b><?php echo $row['english_word']; ?></b><br>
            Filipino word: <b><?php echo $row['filipino_word']; ?></b><br>
            Maranao word: <b><i><?php echo $row['maranao_word']; ?></i></b><br>
            Definition:
<?php 
    } 
?>
        <div style="width:600px; border:0px solid orange; margin-left: 79px; word-wrap:break-word; margin-top: -18px;"><b><?php echo $row['definition'] ?></b></div>
<?php
    // AM - Update the previous word and the row count
    $previous_word = $row["english_word"];
    $row++;
}

// AM - close the last word definition
if ($row > 0) { echo "</div><br>"; }
```

Comment: @user3808774 The `<br>` should go After each word, right? I'll update the answer with that, and if it's a different thing, then leave me a comment and I'll review it. The idea would be to put it after the closing `</div>`

Comment: the footer is also affected

Comment: How is the footer affected? There isn't a footer in the code above.

Comment: The margin of the footer is affected every time I search for a word.

Comment: I fixed one bug in my code (`if ($row > 0) { echo "</div><br>"; }`). About the error with the footer, it could be because of too many closing `</div>`s before the footer (but I cannot know without seeing the code).

Comment: Here's my code for the footer error
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pk4pq6rer9ozc99/debug.php?dl=0